# Bind de tipo complexo com AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Estou estudando AngularJS e Asp.net MVC e não consegui fazer bind de uma propriedade CPF da classe Pessoa quando realizo um POST:

**Classe Pessoa:**

```
public class Pessoa
{
   protected PessoaFisica() { }

   public Int32 PessoaFisicaID{ get; set; }
   public String Nome { get; set; }
   public Cpf CPF { get; set; } 
   ...

}
```

**Classe CPF:**

```
public partial class Cpf
{
        protected Cpf() { }        
        public Int64 Numero { get; private set; }
        ...
}
```

**Controller AngularJS:**

```
...
vm.salvar = function () {

            var pessoaFisica = new Object();
            pessoaFisica.PessoaFisicaID = vm.PessoaFisicaID;
            pessoaFisica.Nome = vm.Nome;

            //Bind do CPF com problema :-(

            //Tentativa 1:
            //pessoaFisica.CPF = new Object();
            //pessoaFisica.CPF.Numero = vm.CPF; 

            //Tentativa 2:
            pessoaFisica.CPF = vm.CPF;

            //Uso o $http.post()
            ajaxService
                    .ajaxPost(
                        pessoaFisica,
                        '/Home/Criar',
                        this.salvarPessoaFisicaOnSuccess,
                        this.salvarPessoaFisicaOnError
                    );   
        }
        ...
```

**Minha Tela:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na primeira tentativa usei o código abaixo, mas não funcionou:

```
//Tentativa 1:
pessoaFisica.CPF = new Object();
pessoaFisica.CPF.Numero = vm.CPF;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro: ***System.MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na segunda tentativa usei o código abaixo e também não funcionou:

```
//Tentativa 2:
pessoaFisica.CPF = vm.CPF;
```

Chega nulo no controller do Asp.net MVC:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu poderia estar ajustando para conseguir fazer o bind do CPF informado?

Comment: Tentou tirar o `private` do `set` da propriedade `Numero` na classe `Cpf`?

Comment: Ajustei o código conforme a resposta do @Randrade, porém continuou com o mesmo erro.

***System.MissingMethodException: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.***

Depois de um bom tempo tentando descobrir ("*debugando*") identifiquei que o erro ocorre porque a classe CPF tem um construtor **protected**, consegui realizar o bind alterando o acesso para **public**. Mas será que a solução é colocar acesso público mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa ajustar sua ViewModel para receber a mesma estrutura que está vindo do seu post request.

```
public class PessoaViewModel
{
    public int PessoaFisicaID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public CPF cpf { get; set; }
}
public class CPFViewModel
{
    public string Numero { get; set; }
}
```

Veja se resolve, e de um retorno.

Comment: Isso resolveria se minha classe CPF tivesse um construtor público. Veja na pergunta que ela não tem. Conforme comentário que adicionei na pergunta, só consegui fazer o bind depois que alterei o construtor da classe CPF de **protected** para **public**. A dúvida agora é: Colocar o construtor da classe CPF como **public** é a solução para fazer bind do objeto pessoa? Seria impossível fazer o post se meu objeto Pessoa se o seu Cpf não tiver um construtor público?

Comment: @Renan, a classe CPF deveria ser CPFViewModel tbm. A ideia é construir um ambiente que receba os valores via request, após isso transporte esses valores para suas classes de modelo.

Comment: Mas então caso eu deixe o contrutor de CPF com acesso **protected** eu vou precisar criar essa classe **de novo** no Asp.net MVC (dessa vez com contrutor *public*) para conseguir fazer o bind? A outra alternativa seria deixar o contrutor de CPF com acesso público para eu não precisar recriar essa classe (como a CPFViewModel), seria isso?

Comment: @Renan, não precisa mexer na sua classe. Basta criar uma classe nova, chamada CPFViewModel, para receber os dados vindos do request. Depois vc passa os dados para um objeto da sua classe CPF.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode resolver esse problema criando o Objeto desta forma:

```
var pessoaFisica = {
    id: 1,
    Nome: 'Renan',
    Cpf: {
        Numero: '232432'
    }
};
```

Mas dessa forma você não está utilizando o AngularJS em si, e sim criando um objeto normal em `javascript`.

Utilizando Angular, seu objeto seria algo como isso:

```
$scope.person = {
  'id': '1',
  'nome': 'Renan',
  'Cpf': {
     'Numero': '1234678'
  },
}
```

E dessa forma você passa o `$scope.person` como objeto.

```
$http.post("Pessoa/Criar/", { person : $scope.person});
```

[Neste site](https://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/angularjs-http-service-ajax-post-json-data-code-example) você possui alguns exemplos de como utilizar Angular.

[Nesta Pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31014111/4843158) você possui alguma respostas de como utilizar Angular para essa finalidade.